# Simple polling of RSS feed to update Spotify playlist in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, cron

I'm trying to learn Google App Engine (and general web app programming) by building a simple app that periodically polls a radio station RSS feed  (~1 request/min), writes the result to a database, and updates a Spotify playlist with the current song. I am using Python with the Flask framework for the web app. I have a simple front-end site which is able to implement the Spotify authentication protocol, however, I am now struggling with the best way to poll information from the RSS feed in the background. I have looked into using the deferred task workflow with Google App Engine Task Queues, but it seems like cron might be a better option for something this simple. The Google App Engine cron docs say to implement a URL call, which is then handled in my app. Is this handled by my Flask URL handlers (ie routes), or by the app engine handlers? My initial thought was that it would look something like this:

In the `cron.yaml` file:

```
cron:
- description: "Poll Song RSS"
  url: /playlistupdate
  schedule: every 1 minute
```

And then in my `routes.py` I would have a route to do the work:

```
@app.route('/playlistupdate')
def playlistupdate ()
    <Send HTTP request to RSS site, store results in SQLite db, add song to spotify playlist via Spotify API>
```

Is this the right idea? Or am I missing something about how the cron flow should work? What happens if a user tries to go to http://[MY_HOSTNAME]/playlistupdate?

Any help on what my options are for a simple background polling flow like this, and how it would work with the Flask framework would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use cron.

Yes, you could implement the handler exactly as you describe.

Yes, you should secure the endpoint, otherwise, anyone would be able to access it.

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron#securing_urls_for_cron) for a way to secure the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I'm testing this out currently, but the basic flow makes sense to me now.